# Get weather information in Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, weather, weather-api

Does someone know how to get weather information in Titanium? I read that the Google Weather API is no longer available. I have tried [this link](http://openweathermap.org/current) but I can't figure out how to put this to work.

Does someone have a working code? I would like to get the weather on my position given by longitude and latitude.

Comment: Use another free API which can be used directly through JavaScript. There a multiple APIs available, for example this one: http://openweathermap.org/examples. Access it via a HTTP request within your code.

Comment: This is the uno that I have tried but not figured out how to put it to work

Comment: I know, but in order to help you to get it to work you have to publish the code which does not work.

Comment: Thanks  Robin Ellerkmann, I figured out a solution with the link you provided and the link that I have tried.

Comment: Great that you was able to find a solution. Please mark your own answer as accepted to show other that you do not need help any more on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    if (e.error) {
        return;
    } else {
        var lon = e.coords.longitude;
        var lat = e.coords.latitude;
        if (Ti.Network.networkType == Ti.Network.NETWORK_NONE) {
            return;
        } else {
            var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
                onload : function(e) {
                    var weather = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    getweatherIcon(weather.weather[0].icon);
                    setweatherText(weather.weather[0].id, weather.main.temp);
                },
                onerror : function(e) {
                },
                timeout : 150000
            });
            client.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=CreatedAppID");
            client.send();
        }
    }
});
```

The "CreatedAppID" is the ID that I have created after creating an account on the provided link that is above.